# Rails form parameters: params[:controller][:variable] or params[:variable]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails controller receiving a form POST, is it better to refer to parameters as `params[:controller][:variable]` or simply `params[:variable]`?

Rails' form helpers appears to name some fields as `controller[variable]` in the view, but the the controller somehow knows how to find the value when the controller uses `params[:variable]`.  In other cases, it doesn't seem to know, particularly when I use a different controller name (e.g. `form_for(@model, :as => :othercontroller, :url => :othercontroller_path(@model))`.

The Rails documentation indicates that `params[:variable]` is sufficient, but this doesn't seem to be the case?

Comment: IMHO, params[:variable] is not associated with any controller. Sometimes, it is associated with model's attributes and sometimes not i.e. independent variables. params[:controller][:variable] gives a value referred to by the name :variable in the hash list :controller.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but whether it is associated with a controller in the params hash (i.e. a nested hash) or not is determined by the naming of the field in the rendered view, and the form helpers do not appear to be consistent, I think, so I am trying to figure out what the convention is.

Comment: The form helpers don't generate `params[:controller][:variable]`, they generate `params[:model][:variable]`.